# Вид многозадачности в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c++

Если я запускаю N потоков через создание объекта thread (ну или async НЕ в отложенном режиме), то 
1. какой вид многозадачности будет использоваться? Кооперативная или вытесняющая?
2. Есть ли инструкция, применив которую в потоке, который выполняется, мы можем снять этот поток с ядра (который в своем коде вызвал эту инструкцию) и поставить другой поток на это ядро (т.е. как бы  осознанно уступить  ресурс другому потоку)?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ зависит от операционной системы, которую Вы используете. Если у Вас относительно новая виндовс или линукс, то будет вытесняющая многозадачность. Если виндовс древний (3.11 вроде), то там будет кооперативная многозадачность. Также кооперативная может быть на некоторых операционных системах для микроконтроллеров.

Второй вопрос - что бы отдать свой квант времени другому, готовому к выполнению потоку, нужно вызывать [Sleep(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: условно говоря, более переносимым вариантов в рамках с++11 будет [`std::this_thread::yield ()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield). Или `thrd_yield()` дял С99. `sleep ()`, как и многое другое ограничен рамками POSIX...

Comment: корпоративная? о_О

Comment: хром ошибки исправил:)